# How to add property in RLMObject which Realm ignores?

Tags: objective-c, realm

I want to add a property of type boolean in a derived RLMObject which is only needed during runtime. So it's not part of the database table. Is there a way to mark the property as not part of the table in Realm?

The reason I need this, is because I want to save the selected state of a uitablecell during runtime. This means, I don't need an extra field in the database table.

I hope my question is clear, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will want to use `ignored properties` of Realm:

**edit:** included the Swift docs link, but the question is about ObjC
https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#ignored-properties

`Override Object.ignoredProperties() to prevent Realm from persisting model properties. Realm won’t interfere with the regular operation of these properties: they’ll be backed by ivars and you can freely override their setters and getters.`

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Dank je wel :)

Answer (score 1):

Realm is noSql database so it has no tables - it stores graph of dependencies. That is why you can just create separate 'settings' class, include it in your realm module (@RealmModule) and store single instance of it in realm file for that module. This will be the single instance of that object in database.

Comment: Whatever technology is used for the database, the question is still valid. Antwan van Houdt gave the correct answer. But I'll update my question based on your post.